# Unit test can not find my methods/functions

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have written a basic unit test however when I try to run it it says it can not find the function I am calling however I know it is there and I have already added the form it is held in to references. Everything else works perfect except my unit test.

This is my unit test code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WindowsFormsApplication1;

namespace Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CheckGameCannotStartWithoutTwoTeamsSelectedTest()
        {
            bool expected, actual;
            WindowsFormsApplication1.RugbyScorer frm1 = new RugbyScorer();
            actual = StartCheck();
            expected = false;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `StartCheck` defined?

Comment: This code calls functions that you haven't provided code for. We can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should't it be:

```
frm1.StartCheck();
```

Comment: You have saved my life man I hate those little mistakes that you never notice I literally had a professor at my uni take a look and he spent 20 minutes and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @JulienPowell Great professor :p

Comment: @JulienPowell : Np. Glad to help